# How to Achieve a Fixed Position of a Control in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

I wanted to align a button all the way to the right. Using the Location property alone didn't work since maximizing the window or changing its size will affect the button's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario above, I set the Anchor property to Top, Right.